# Resetting zoom in kendo ui mobile does not work correctly

Tags: android, jquery, ios, kendo-ui

We are building a mobile app with an image gallery with **kendo ui mobile**.
For the image gallery we use **kendo ui mobile** `scrollview` where you can `swipe` through the images.

Currently we are trying to implement `zoom` where users can `zoom in` and `out` of the images. `Pinch to zoom` works fine in the gallery with `data-zoom="true"`. We also reset the zoom if the user double taps with the following code:

`app.scroller().scrollElement.css("-webkit-transform", "")`;

This also works fine but the problem arise if you z**oom, reset and zoom again**. If you zoom the second time the image immediately resizes back to the size it was before the reset. It looks like kendo holds a different zoom value internally.

Is there a better way to reset the zoom?

Thank you very much

Best regards

Mark